# Getting object from body returns wrong property values when it has TimeSpan properties

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

My ASP.NET Web API controller method takes a custom object:

```
[HttpPost, Route("...{id}...")]
public async Task<long> Post(long id, Timesheet timesheet) {
    ... //only one of timesheet's properties are properly set, the DateTime
    return result;
}
```

This is the Timesheet class (obfuscated, sorry):

```
public class Timesheet
{
    //This DateTime is the only property that gets converted properly
    public DateTime a { get; set; } 
    public int b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan d { get; set; } //System.Timespan
    public TimeSpan e { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public long g { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}
```

When I remove the two `TimeSpan` properties from the class, all properties are properly converted. I'm using the default formatters/converters, and I'm receiving the information as `application/json`. I'm using `ASP.NET Web API 5.2.3` and `.NET Framework 4.5.2`.

Both when I send (from client) and receive (in the client) the `TimeSpan`, it gets the format `"d":"07:30:00"`, which should be correct. `Newtonsoft.Json` agrees anyway. So when I send from the API to the client, it gets serialized and deserialized right. But when I serialize it right from the client, it doesn't get deserialized correctly, via the default formatter/convert/whatever-it-is.

Is this a bug?

I currently don't have the time to test it further, but my quick fix was to convert it manually via `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` (6.0.4):

```
[HttpPost, Route("...{id}...")]
public async Task<long> Post(long id, HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var response = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var timesheet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Timesheet>(response);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1. Check format of TimeSpan in json. It looks like it has been serialized bad. 2. About your fix: don't block thread calling .Result. Use async action with await.

Comment: I second @mtkachenko's suggestions.

Comment: "d":"07:30:00" is a correct timespan in json. Check https://dotnetfiddle.net/7krGdS

Comment: I added the format to the question. I'm not very experienced with asynchronous calls, but wouldn't awaiting the result be almost identical to not doing so, when I'm using the result variable in my very next line of code? Or would it both create a thread for reading the string, and finishing the controller method, while using the main thread elsewhere? Or am I completely off track?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/805923/Asynchronous-programming-in-Web-API-ASP-NET-MVC about async actions.

Comment: Actually it's not clear for me what's your problem. Have TimeSpan properties been serialized properly?

Comment: Yes, I would assume they have been serialized properly. When sending my json in the client, just before converting them to a byte array, I get a properly formed json (also done by Newtonsoft.Json): `{"a":"2016-10-06T14:47:07.7762632Z","b":60,"c":"test","d":"07:30:00","e":"11:45:00","f":"test","g":11,"h":15}`. My problem is that I don't understand why removing the TimeSpan properties on both sides fixes the issue, when it is the exact same format that the default formatter sends to the client when I use a `GET` method with the same Timesheet class.

Comment: So Timesheet class isn't deserialized properly in case of GET method? Is it your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, that's the problem. Do you have a suggestion on how I could make that more clear in the question? I thought that much was clear. Maybe that is too meta for this comment section though. On a sidenote, I've read up on async operations last night, and converted everything relevant to async operations. Thanks, that'll probably be needed in production release for a few thousand users next week :P